# Line break in set /p

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

In one of my batch scripts I want the user to be able to enter some text.The text will then be written to a .txt file:

```
    @echo Enter an archive comment here (English letters and numbers only):
    set /p textfileContents= 
::  Outputs the user input to the text file
    @echo %textfileContents% > %textfileName%.txt
```

This works fine except that I am limited to a single line of text, because hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute the command instead of making a line break.

How can I get a line break instead of executing the command?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
copy con %textfileName%.txt
```

At the end of typing your multi-line text type **CTRL+Z** or **CTRL+C**